# DataSet Designer loads XML instead of the Table View

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, .net-2.0

I have a DataSet.xsd file in a class library project.  When I double click on the file instead of seeing the table diagram I am presented with XML.  Does anyone know what's going on, and how I can get my Table Diagram back?

Comment: Did you try right-clicking in Visual Studio and selecting "Open With"?  That generates a dialog that lets you select what to open it with and also the default for what that file type opens with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a multi-part solution that had several cascading symptoms.  I don't really understand the cause of the problem which is concerning, but this at least put me back to coding.

**Primary Problem:**

**Step 1:** 
Tried `devenv /resetsettings` in the VS Command Prompt per the [ASP.NET Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1116852.aspx) link and it **FAILED**.

**Step 2:** Tried `devenv /resetskippkgs` in the VS Command Prompt per the [ASP.NET Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1116852.aspx) link and it **PASSED**.

**Issue:**

Right clicking on a table adapter and selecting configure would result in this error message:

> Configure TableAdapter XXX Failed. Unable to find connection 'xxx' for
>   object 'settings'. The connection string could not be found in
>   application settings, or the data provider associated with the
>   connection string could not be loaded.

**Step 1:** Looked in all of my .xsd files for multiple definitions of a connection string.  In my case there were none acrossed several files. [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/)  **FAILED**

**Step 2:** Tried deleting the connection string setting and rebuilding it from scratch in the settings.settings pane.  **FAILED**

**Step 3:** Changed all of my DefaultConnectionindex's in the .xsd files to 1. Interesting how conflicted the answers inside [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/) are.  Some said 0, some said 1. I am not confident my fix had anything to do with me ultimately. Visual Studio appeared to create the bug somehow, and just the same appeared to take care of it.  **PASSED**

**Issue**

After re-configuring my Table Adapter I was given the following error when trying to save changes:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

**Step 1:** Restarted my machine and made the changes to the table adapter again and the changes were saved. **PASSED**

Answer (score 1):

goto your Solutions Explorer. right click the dataset you are trying to open up. Click "Open With" you should get a dialog box come up, select "Dataset Editor" and press ok.

From here on you should be all set again.

Steve